# Issues while calling Sitecore API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have used mvc 5 captcha in my sitecore 8.1 based web application.But after hardening the captcha was not visible.Does any one face this kind of issues.Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by  "hardening" in this context?

Comment: Hardening is adding comprehensive security instructions to harden the security of Sitecore.

Comment: @VikramDevasenapathy can you give us more details about "hardening"? What exactly was done?

Comment: @Anton Please refer below URL for reference https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_hardening

Answer (score 0):

If the captcha Image is not displaying on the WFFM form. I imagine the configuration settings required for the Captcha are no longer present after your actions.

You need to ensure the following settings are present in are in the web.config under the node configuration/system.webServer/handers if you're using iis7 or above

```xml
<add name="CaptchaImage" verb="*" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
<add name="CaptchaAudio" verb="*" path="CaptchaAudio.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
```

See this [link for more informatio](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/03/23/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-captcha-not-rendering-correctly/)n or how to complete it in IIs 6

Comment: It was not a WFFM form.We use MVC Captcha (https://www.nuget.org/packages/CaptchaMvc.Mvc5/)